# mysqli - cannot add or update child row - foreign key constraint fails

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

A have created a table that has connection to two other tables.

[image]

As you can see it is "many to many" connection.

Now, I am trying to insert some data:

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO `TasksMarks` (`UserID`, `TaskID`, `Mark`) VALUES ('$userID', '$taskID', '$mark')");
```

When trying to do so, I get this mistake:

[image]

I am sure that data types are the same (they both INT).

Comment: How are the variables you use set?

Comment: $taskID = $_POST['taskID'];
$mark = $_POST['mark'];$user->id

Comment: Have you tried `var_dump` to check their variable type?

Comment: The first one is AUTO_INCREMENT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple reason because you are trying to add/insert a key in `TasksMarks(UserID)` table which probably doesn't exists in `users(ID)` table.

Comment: Yes it helped. I just forgot to write session_start()! And tried to get id like $_SESSION['id']